# How do I map array of structs from XML to Array (IList/IEnumerable) of objects using XML-RPC by CookComputing in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, xml-rpc

Is there a way to transfer/map an array of structs (in XML) to an array of objects in C# .NET via XML-RPC using cook-computing library ?

For instance, I want to send this array to XML-RPC server:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>mynamespace.methodName</methodName>
   <params>
      <param>
       <value>
         <array>
          <data>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>param1String</name>
                    <value><string>ABCDEFGH</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>param2Int</name>
                    <value><i4>123456</i4></value>
                </member>
            </struct>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>param1String</name>
                    <value><string>QWERTY</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>param2Int</name>
                    <value><i4>987654</i4></value>
                </member>
            </struct> 
          </data>
         </array>
       </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

furthermore, I have the following server method to process this request:

```
    [XmlRpcMethod("mynamespace.methodName")]
    public void ProcessArrayOfObjects(Array[] myArray)
    //public void ProcessArrayOfObjects(XmlRpcStruct[] myArray)
    {
        try
        {
          // ... would process, but myArray is empty
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e, "Processing array failed! Reason: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am using 3rd party XML-RPC library by CookComputing in order to process XML requests.
All I get after mapping the received XML input to `Array[]`, or `XmlRpcStruct[]`, or even array of concrete classes, is an empty array.

I also tried to map it to a `List<XmlRpcStruct>`, or `List<ConcreteObject>`, while removed `<array></array>` and `<data></data>` tags. I got XML-RPC request error (wrong XML format).

What else can I do with CookComputing framework ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is this:
I need to wrap each of my `<struct></struct>`  to a `<value></value>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>mynamespace.methodName</methodName>
   <params>
      <param>
       <value>
         <array>
          <data>
           <value> 
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>param1String</name>
                    <value><string>ABCDEFGH</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>param2Int</name>
                    <value><i4>123456</i4></value>
                </member>
            </struct>
           </value> 
           <value> 
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>param1String</name>
                    <value><string>QWERTY</string></value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>param2Int</name>
                    <value><i4>987654</i4></value>
                </member>
            </struct>
           </value> 
          </data>
         </array>
       </value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```